# Let $f$ be an entire function and suppose , $|f(z)+(1-2i)|\geq \epsilon,$ for all $z\in \mathbb{C}$. Prove that $f$ is constant.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration, entire-functions

Let $f$ be an entire function and suppose that for some $\epsilon>0$, $$|f(z)+(1-2i)|\geq \epsilon,$$ for all $z\in \mathbb{C}$. Prove that $f$ is constant.

What I know so far is that, Liouvilles Theorem will be used in proving the $f$ is constant. Since $f$ is already entire, I have to show that it is bounded. I know that it is bounded below by $\epsilon$, however, I can't bound it above. My Professor said that this has to do something with annular domain. But I can't figure it out.

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: It's "LiouUville", not "LioNville".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: Consider the function
$$\frac{1}{f(z) + (1-2i)}.$$
On what domain is this function analytic?

Comment: Is that $f(z)-(1-2i)$ or $f(z)+(1-2i)$?

Comment: You are indeed right, it should be $(f(z) + (1-2i)$. I'll change it.

Comment: then $g(z)=\displaystyle \left| \frac{1}{f(z)+(1-2i)}\right| \leq \frac{1}{\epsilon}=0$, so $g(z)$ bounded? but not necessary entire. There is a chance that the denominator becomes 0.

Comment: Can I choose $\epsilon$ small enough so that it contains $f(z_0)=-1+2i$? So that $g(z)$ is entire? Just an idea.

Comment: @FlickerBeat : There is no such $z_0$ by the inequality in the assumption.

Comment: @LutzL: Yeah. I just figured it out. Hehe I think I got the solution. Thank you everyone.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Consider $1/g$ where $g$ is your function $f$ plus the constant., prove this is bounded, and apply Liouville’s theorem. If $1/f$ is constant, then so is $g$, hence $f$.